# Pyomo Solver Windows pop-up

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using the algebric modeling Pyomo within Python to solve my optimization problems. However, every time I am running a solver, i.e. Cplex, IPOPT there is a window popping up. Any idea on how to turn off the pop-up windows?

Comment: How are you running Python? If it's through an IDE like Spyder or Pycharm then my guess is there is an option to control the window.

Comment: I am using Spyder IDE to run my Pyomo codes. I searched a little bit online but I was unable to find any option to control windows pop up in Spyder. Any suggestions?